# Which openstack version will be installed with juju?

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, versions

I'm a newbie with MAAS and Juju, I'd like to know which openstack version will be installed with juju on MAAS ? Is it the latest version or can I choose my version ?

Answer (score 4):

By default, the Ubuntu distribution default will be installed when the charms are deployed. At the time of this post, it looks like this:

- trusty: Icehouse.
- utopic: Juno
- vivid: Kilo

However, you can opt to use Juno or Kilo on trusty with the Cloud Archive. The charms have configuration options to allow you to change versions at deployment time.

Be aware that Kilo is very much still in development. Trusty + Icehouse is considered the current long-term support option and what you'll get by default when you deploy with Juju.

This page provides an outline of the supported combinations:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ServerTeam/CloudArchive